# Changing roles in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, roles

I created the app with the help of rails composer. Using devise for authentication and cancan for managing roles. So I have 3 roles by default: Admin, User and VIP. I deleted VIP, because I don't need it. Run rake db:seed to create a default admin. Then I'm coming to localhost and seeing the "First User" as admin. I logout and register(signup) a new user. Then, signing in again as admin. I see, that by deafault, this new user doesn't have any role. And also I see, that I can change it("Change role" - button). I push it and as admin can choose whether new user will be the second admin or just User. I choose, for example, User, push "change role" and have an "ArgumentError in UsersController#update wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)".

Sooo, I have two questions: 
1. How to give my admin the ability to change roles without errors. 
2. How to make new signing up users to have default role "User".

Thanks!

Ok, I managed to set the default role this way:

```
 after_create :assign_reader_role
private
 def assign_reader_role
  self.add_role "user"
end
```

Here is my UserControlle:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!


  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    user = User.find(params[:id])  
   if user.update_attributes(user_params)
     redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
   else
     redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
   end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize! :destroy, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    user = User.find(params[:id])
   unless user == current_user
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
   else
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Can't delete yourself."
    end
   end
    private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
   end
```

Here is models. 
User: 
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      after_create :assign_reader_role
      rolify
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,#:confirmable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

```
  validates_presence_of :name

 private
 def assign_reader_role
    self.add_role "user"
  end
 end
```

Role:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
 belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  scopify
end
```

UserController I've already put! And where can I take params from the form?

Comment: Oh, forgot to say, "Delete"-button works perfect. It deletes the user without any errors.

Comment: add params which comes from the form and write line where the error is raised

Comment: Line 17.  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
Whereas I'm a little bit newbie in rails, could you please tell me, where can I see the params, which come from the form

Comment: have you setup attr_accessible in model `User`?

Comment: in rails 4 it is made different way, in controller. So you can tell me what I should set up and I'll do that.

Comment: Ups... I thought it is 3rd Rails :)
You should read about strong_parameters (https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)
and remove `:as => :admin` from update_attributes

Comment: OK, I made it!! For now I don't see the error anymore! But nothing is changing after choosing the other role and pushing the button "Change role". Any ideas?

Comment: It is necessary to know how `User`, `Role`, and user form are implemented.
I can suppose that params are build incorrectly. It is necessary to check and try

Comment: You mean User and Role models? And where can I find user form? If you need this, I'll put it here.

Comment: 1. Models `User`, `Role`. 2. Controller code 3. params which comes from form

Comment: params can be taken from the server log

Comment: this is my case!! Maybe it will be more clear what to do!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034494/wrong-number-of-arguments-2-for-1-rails-4-maybe-strong-params-issue/18760728#18760728

Comment: (I did not notice user_params yesterday) I think you missed role_ids in this code `params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)`

Comment: this can help to understand what is going in strong_parameters http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html

Comment: gotva, you can answer the question and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed `role_ids` in `permit`

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role_ids)
end
```